# How to include external shell scripts with bdist_wheel in python?

Tags: python, github, pip

I've been trying to solve this error and just cannot find a way around it. I'm sure it's just some stupid, small mistake in my configuration but cannot figure it out... See my code repository in https://github.com/tovrleaf/git-utils

### Problem

By running `pip3 uninstall -y guts && python setup.py bdist_wheel && pip3 install dist/guts-*.whl && guts branch list-merged` for project in project in project root, it returns an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/git-utils-.../lib/python3.8/site-packages/gutscli/services/../../scripts/branch-list.sh'

For some reason, install doesn't include wanted shell scripts in package, even tho it's displayed in install output copying build/scripts-3.8/branch-list.sh -> build/bdist.macosx-10.15-x86_64/wheel/guts-0.0.0.data/script

Running ./src/gutscli/guts.py branch list-merged works ok!

I even created issue to my own personal repository about it.
https://github.com/tovrleaf/git-utils/issues/1

Comment: You want to add non-Python (.sh) files to your wheel, correct?

Comment: Yes! I try to do it here https://github.com/tovrleaf/git-utils/blob/master/setup.py#L27

Comment: Are you able to include the files using the code example below?

Comment: Hi, thanks I got it working :) The actual problem was that I was using bdist_wheel and not sdist. But your answer got me good pointers! Thanks alot

Comment: It works with `bdist_wheel` as well. I always and only use wheels for distribution and including external files works fine with the `setup.py` below :)

Comment: Did it work for you then?

Comment: Yes, solution here https://github.com/tovrleaf/git-utils/blob/master/Makefile#L15 - I also used MANIFEST.in to ease things out. Didn't quite use your solution then but got good points! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any files to your wheel using the `setup.py` `package_data`.
With the helper function I provided in the following example, you can also specify a folder (a web panel source folder for example) that gets added recursively.

In your `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools
from shutil import rmtree
import os


def package_files(directories: list):
    """
    This function will return the path of all files in the directories
    recursively, as setup.py package_data cannot handle * placeholders
    """
    paths = []
    for directory in directories:
        for (path, directories, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                paths.append(os.path.join('..', path, filename))
    return paths


# add all paths that you want to add recursively to package_files()
# NOTE: this path is relative to the setup.py
my_fancy_script_files = package_files(
                            [
                                "./path/to/your/script/folder/", # my scripts
                                "./path/to/other/stuff/", # other nice stuff
                            ]
                        )

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    package_data={'': my_fancy_script_files}, # you can put various files here (as a list)
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

if you have further questions or if it doesn't work on your project, leave a comment and post your project source tree for further debugging :)